# Using AWS SDK to upload file to S3 in .NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, aws-sdk, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm attempting to use [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html) documentation to upload a file to my S3 bucket using the AWS SDK.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any documentation giving an example of how to do this in .NET Core, only how to create and inject an instance of `IAmazonS3`.

Here is what I have:

```
private IAmazonS3 client; //Being injected
private string bucketName;

using (client)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = "keyTest",
        ContentBody = "sample text"
    };
    var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
}
```

When it calls the `PutObjectAsync()` line, it hangs for 30 seconds or so and then throws a "The HTTP redirect request failed" exception.

All the documentation I'm seeing is for `PutObject()` not `PutObjectAsync()`.  The `client` instance I have only exposes async methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brutal.  I had my `IAmazonS3` client pointing at `us-west-1`, but it was a different region (`us-west-2`).